# els-cas-templates references not displaying correctly using PDFLaTeX

Tags: bibliographies, els-cas

I download the contents of the `els-cas-templates` LaTeX files [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/els-cas-templates/?lang=en), extract it into a new folder.

- I firstly open up the pdf document and check the references are displaying correctly, before re-compiling (which they are).
- I next open up the `cas-dc-template` LaTeX file.
- I select the compilation options to `PdfLaTeX + Bib(la)tex + PdfLaTeX (x2) + See PDF`.
- I then run the `PDFLaTeX` compilation and click `see PDF`.

Now the references have changed to `[? ] [? ? ][? ? ]` and I get the warning for the references as follows `Citation` Fortunato2010' on page 1 undefined`.

I have tried changing the `\bibliographystyle{cas-model2-names}` to a harvard referencing style and `plainnat` etc. but still get the same issue.

Any reason after downloading the template my compilation is not finding the references? They appear in the pdf document after downloading it so they have been able to compile correctly on a different computer.

Comment: Have a look at the `.blg` file. What does it say?

Comment: No `.blg` file gets created... I am using Windows 10 with Texmaker. In the folder where the files are I do not see a file with the type `.blg`.

Comment: Note that Windows 10 may classify `.blg` files as "Performance monitor files" or some such and may hide their extension. The `.blg` file is a simple text file you can open with any text editor. If there is indeed no `.blg` file, that means you did not run BibTeX. You need to run BibTeX as explained in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864, so that a full compile sequence is LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX (where "LaTeX" is your favourite flavour of LaTeX: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX).

Comment: Thanks! running BibTex and then running PDFLaTeX seems to have solved the issue.